# Run command on multiple subfolders on cmd

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-prompt

I have a lot of courses in subfolders that I have downloaded under (`C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Local\lynda.com\Lynda.com Desktop App\offline\ldc_dl_courses`) and I want to run this command on all subfolders under ldc_dl_courses but  I have some problems creating a batch file to run it.

```
LyndaDecryptor /D “C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Local\lynda.com\Lynda.com Desktop App\offline\ldc_dl_courses\143455” /DB “C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Local\lynda.com\Lynda.com Desktop App\db.sqlite” /OUT “C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Local\lynda.com\Lynda.com Desktop App\offline\ldc_dl_courses\mp4”
```

I tried this but it didn't work

```
FOR /D %G IN ("C:\Users\salah\AppData\Local\lynda.com\Lynda.com Desktop App\offline\ldc_dl_courses") DO LyndaDecryptor /D "C:\Users\salah\AppData\Local\lynda.com\Lynda.com Desktop App\offline\ldc_dl_courses\%G" /DB "C:\Users\salah\AppData\Local\lynda.com\Lynda.com Desktop App\db.sqlite" /OUT "C:\Users\salah\AppData\Local\lynda.com\Lynda.com Desktop App\offline\ldc_dl_courses\mp4"
```

Comment: To get a listing of all folders you can use a `FOR /D` command. Open up a cmd prompt and type: `FOR /?` to see the help file.

Comment: Use doublequotes not smart quotes!

Comment: @thesalah1212, please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50056295/edit) to add your content above to it, _properly formatted_, then delete those two comments.

Comment: You haven't given the `FOR` command anything to look for.  After the `IN` you must tell it what it needs to find.  If the `(set)` was optional the help syntax would put it within [brackets].

Comment: Use `for /r` or use `dir /s /b` to create a list oft directories

Comment: @thesalah1212, do not put that much code in a comment.  You need to edit your question with any new code you are trying to use.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using following batch file for this task:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
set "LyndaAppFolder=%LocalAppData%\lynda.com\Lynda.com Desktop App"
set "CoursesFolder=%LyndaAppFolder%\offline\ldc_dl_courses"
for /D %%I in ("%CoursesFolder%\*") do if /I not "%%I" == "%CoursesFolder%\mp4" LyndaDecryptor.exe /D "%%I" /DB "%LyndaAppFolder%\db.sqlite" /OUT "%CoursesFolder%\mp4"
endlocal
```

It is unclear for me if `mp4` in courses folder is a folder or file. I suppose it is a folder which should be skipped on processing all non hidden subfolders in courses folder which is the reason for the additional case-insensitive **IF** condition.

The command **FOR** searches because of `/D` for non hidden directories in specified directory matching the wildcard pattern `*` and assigns the name of a found directory with full path without surrounding double quotes to loop variable `I`. The name of a found directory would be assigned to loop variable `I` without path if just `*` would be used in round brackets because of current directory is the directory containing the courses directories.

I suppose that `LyndaDecryptor` is an executable with file extension `.exe` and appended the file extension on last but one command line. Best would be to specify `LyndaDecryptor` with full path and with file extension as in this case Windows command interpreter has not to search for an executable or script with that file name on each iteration of the loop.

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `for /?`
- `if /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`

See also Wikipedia article about [Windows Environment Variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable#Windows) for predefined environment variable `LOCALAPPDATA` used in the batch file using CamelCase notation for better readability as environment variables are not case-sensitive on Windows in comparison to **FOR** loop variables which are case-sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

```
FOR /D %G IN ("C:\Users\[u]\AppData\Local\lynda.com\Lynda.com Desktop App\offline\ldc_dl_courses\*") DO LyndaDecryptor /D "%G" /DB "C:\Users\[u]\AppData\Local\lynda.com\Lynda.com Desktop App\db.sqlite" /OUT "C:\Users\[u]\AppData\Local\lynda.com\Lynda.com Desktop App\offline\mp4"
```

this is the following working solution